# Object is nil but code interpret not as nil

Tags: ios

I want to check if an object I get from the server is nil or not, if nil I want to use a placeholder image, if not nil I want to use the image from the url. Debugger says imageUrl is nil, but my code evaluates it as not nil.
the code always crash at

```
providerImg.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: GPProfiles[indexPath.row]["image"] as! String))
```

[image]

I have also tried this

```
let imageUrl = GPProfiles[indexPath.row]["image"]
if imageUrl != nil {
    providerImg.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: GPProfiles[indexPath.row]["image"] as! String))
} else{
    providerImg.image = UIImage(named: "placeholderImage.png")
}
```

How can I check if an object is nil ???  Thanks

> UPDATE TO ANSVWER BY @andre-slotta
>   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
if let imageUrl = GPProfiles[indexPath.row]["image"] as? String {
    ...
}
```

since your `!= nil` check does not seem to work here you get some more info about `nil`, `NULL` and `NSNull`: [nshipster.com/nil](http://nshipster.com/nil)

Comment: because this statements checks if the content of `GPProfiles[indexPath.row]["image"]` is a string (which is what you expect). if not (for example if it is `nil`) it continues with the `else` case...

Comment: Ok, so why can't I explicitly check for nil ?

Comment: Lol, I think so too ! but nope

Comment: can you please print out `imageUrl` after this line: `let imageUrl = GPProfiles[indexPath.row]["image"]`?

Comment: done, updated question with the log and debugger info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116318/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-karlml).